# How to get old console logs (javascript)

Tags: javascript, console

I want to get a list of logs which are sent to browser's console. Is there any way to do it.

```
console.log("lol");
console.log("imao");

list
->["lol", "imao"]
```

Comment: not without overriding `console.log` yourself. Because the console can log *far* more than just strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740553/mike-pomax-kamermans) mentioned, overriding the original `.log()` function / method, would be a better choice ...

```js
let list = [];

let log = console.log;  //backup log fn
console.log = (...args) => {  //override log fn
  list.push(...args);
  log(...args);
};

console.log('lol');
console.log('lmao');
console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up preserve logs option on the browser console tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can hijack JavaScript functions

```
(function(){
    var oldLog = console.log;
    console.log = function (message) {
        // DO MESSAGE HERE.
        oldLog.apply(console, arguments);
    };
})();
```